# Bootstrap Mobile Vertical Spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap to design a website but i'm finding problems to control the vertical spacing of the website on mobile view because the elements are either sticking or too far apart when switched to mobile view.

is there anything that boostrap offers to increase or decrease the spacing, such as **col-xx-offset-#** for the horizontal gapping?

Or is there any other standard method to control this?

Code Example with inline style:

https://jsfiddle.net/6e513k5o/

```
<div class="container">
        <div>
            <div style="color: #555;border: 3px solid #ed008c;border-radius: 4px; padding:10px" class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-3">
                <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:auto" src="http://placehold.it/231x213">
            </div>
            <div style="color: #555;border: 3px solid #ed008c;border-radius: 4px; padding:10px;margin-top:100px;margin-left:-3px;" class="col-md-3">
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <label>
                        Mr. John Doe
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <p>
                        CEO
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please, provide your code.

Comment: @NitinDhomse added an example

Comment: in your code, you are not yousing col-sm-XX and col-xs-XX  which is specifically useful for small devices.

Answer (score 0):

use `<div class="row">` after `<div class="container">`

Comment: tried it, that's why i have an div without class after the container, try it and link me the jsfiddle if you can

Answer (score 0):

The good thing about bootstrap is that you can customize it as per your need.

Please add a custom margin for columns. Please find the updated fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/6e513k5o/6/

> HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2  col-md-3 custom-class">
      <img class="img-responsive" style="margin:auto" src="http://placehold.it/231x213">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 custom-class">
      <div style="text-align:center">
        <label>
          Mr. John Doe
        </label>
        <br>
        <p>
          CEO
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

> CSS

```
.custom-class {
  color: #555;
  border: 3px solid #ed008c;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: but then the normal view got pushed way too much. i think adding a media query will solve it, but isn't there a bootstrap or a standard method to change vertical spacing?

Comment: No, there is no bootstrap standard for this AFAIK.